# Edit System Environment Variable Using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to add python path to the system evironment path by python.

I've tried

`os.eviron['Path'] += ';C:/Anaconda3/'`

However, I found this only make a difference in the script. I checked the system and didn't find `;C:/Anaconda3/` in the environment variable 'Path', which makes command `python xxx.py` can not be recognized by the system.

Is there any function or method to edit the system evironment path by python?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the spelling from **environ** to **eviron**?

or...

Maybe a quick batch script could help you do the trick as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3701730/12484756). In the same question, you can find a way to do in python which would not survive a reboot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072284/12484756), but could do the trick.

Comment: Oops, I misspelled it. I've tried this but it just work inside the script. Maybe I'd better call py script using the full path of python.exe.